# connect to a SFTP server from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, sftp, azure-functions

I am connecting to SFTP from pre-complied Azure function using Renci.SshNet. I am successfully able to connect, upload a file to destined location.

My credentials are stored in clear text in local.settings.json. I need to know any subtle way to connect to SFTP but clear text. I am more curious to know if I could use sftp_SFTP connection string (created in Azure portal).

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Settings from `local.settings.json` are only for local development. When you deploy Functions to Azure, the settings will be taken from App Settings, which you can define via portal.

You can use [External File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file) output binding to connect to SFTP.

Comment: I would like to go ahead with Azure functions and I do get your point about local.settings.json. Could I use/decode the sftp_SFTP connector (defined in azure portal and also in local settings.json), to establish connection to SFTP.

"sftp_SFTP": "Endpoint=https://logic-apis-upsidedown.azure-apim.net/apim/sftp/abcd/;Scheme=Key;AccessToken=someguid".

Comment: Updated my answer